# How does the client part communicate with a service with RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-rabbit

I am currently learning the microservice architecture with rabbitMQ to communicate between them. I got the idea to manage the communication between different microservices but I don't really find out how does the client can manage to communicate with my microservices.

For example if I create a user via my web app, do I have to send the request to the exchange directly that will send it to the account service (how can I send it to my exchange?) or do I need a sort of API Gateway to get all my request and then transfer to the exchange?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you need a gateway of some sort. More info here: https://microservices.io/
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I already saw this image but I didn't understand why the mobile is connected to the API Gateway directly and the web app to a storefront and not an API Gateway. Is the storefront an API Gateway like AWS Cloudfront could be? Or does Storefront is a service ?

Comment: In this particular case/image, the mobile app has its own UI, and all it additionally needs is an access to a storage layer, via API. A browser uses a web app, which offers another UI and which is already located in the subnet of the microservices, so it can access microservices directly. In contrast to the mobile app which is located on a user's phone. One remark though. A web app could have used the API to access micro services in order to reduce the duplication of code. But I guess they just wanted to show the possibilities only.